# Unity VideoPlayer Framecount is always zero while playing

Tags: unity-game-engine

VideoPlayer.Framecount is always returning zero while playing the video in unity. Any help to get the framecount would be appreciated.

Comment: Gotta show us some code and describe the situation more!

Comment: This is the line gameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer> ().frameCount .. as per the documentation [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-frameCount.html), this should return the number of frames in the video content. .

Comment: Gotta show us a lot more code so we know where things are going wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Save the frameCount when video starts.

```
m_videoPlayer.started += e =>
{
    m_frameCount = m_videoPlayer.frameCount;
};
```